# Perpendicular vectors out of a set

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

I stumbled on this problem and I wanna know if there is a better solution. 
There are $n$ 3d vectors with $x$, $y$, and $z$ components and I wanna find all pairs of perpendicular vectors in this set. Is there any better way than to verify all possible pairs of 3 vectors, some kind of optimization (not the obvious ones)?

Comment: You want to know the better solution, what is your solution? What are obvious optimizations?

Comment: I think this is his solution "to verify all possible pairs" @Evil

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be solved in time $\tilde{O}(n^{4/3})$, using several algorithms:

- Agarwal, [Partitioning arrangements of lines II: Applications](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~pankaj/publications/papers/cutting2.pdf).
- Chazelle, [Cutting hyperplanes for divide-and-conquer](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/CuttingHyperplanes.pdf).
- Matoušek, [Range searching with efficient hierarchical cuttings](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02573972).

There is an essentially matching lower bound due to Erickson, [New lower bounds for Hopcroft's problem](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/hopcroft.pdf). See also Williams and Yu, [Finding orthogonal vectors in discrete structures](http://theory.stanford.edu/~yuhch123/files/orthog-soda.pdf).